# multi-view, how to change property in one view from 2nd view

Tags: knockout.js

Here is the jsfiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/8vQrA/

I want to change a property in View #1 from View #2. When Section 2 is initialized, Section 1 is passed as a reference and I change the property of that there but it doesn't change in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property on view 1 is nested in the `section1` object and is an observable, so you would need to set it like:

```
var section2View = function(s1){
    var self = this;
    self.s1 = s1;
    self.section2= { property: ko.observable("test2") };
    self.s1.section1.property("test3");
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8vQrA/1/